# Multiple screens

Tags: android, android-layout

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initControls();

    }
```

I'm a noob android coder. I have written a one-screen app that functions as I want, but I'd like to add additional screens, i.e press a button and a new screen opens, press a button, previous screen is restored. How can I add views to my program?  My one xml file is res/layout/main.xml. How can I add additional views and switch between them at will?  I'm using ant and the console to develop...no Eclipse.

Thanks for helping a noob :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take a Look at [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and [Activties](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).. Here is a good example.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/65.html

Intents are used to pass from one actvity to another and Activity is simply a screen with UI widgets on it to interact.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to add a new screen to your application.

The primary way is to create another Activity such as the one you have there, but attach a different xml layout to it. You can see how to invoke another activity here. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

You can also use widgets made just for this task, such as the ViewFlipper or the ViewPager.

It's probably best for you to read through the basics of the Android documentation to decide what is best for your application. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html